# Unable to call Rcpp's factorial Function with a Scalar

Tags: r, rcpp

I define a c++ function in R, it is:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
'double foo(double t, int k) {
    double x = t/factorial(k);
}')
```

When I run this function in R, I receive an error:

> file59b051c6b334.cpp:7:25: error: no matching function for call to 'factorial'
>
> ```
> NumericVector x = t/factorial(k);
>
>                     ^~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/math.h:59:19:
>
> note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to
>   'SEXP' (aka 'SEXPREC *') for 1st argument VECTORIZED_MATH_1(factorial 
>   , ::Rcpp::internal::factorial   )
>
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/sugar/block/Vectorized_Math.h:91:9:
>
> note: expanded from macro 'VECTORIZED_MATH_1'
>
> ```
>     __NAME__( SEXP x){ return __NAME__( NumericVector( x ) ) ; }
> ```

Could anybody please help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should also get an error about not returning anything from the function (I think you need a `return x;` statement

Comment: @SymbolixAU Even I add this return statement, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is two fold:

1. The `factorial` function is part of `VECTORIZED_MATH_1` that requires a `Rcpp::NumericVector` parameter.
2. You are missing a `return` statement.

Use:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
    'Rcpp::NumericVector foo(double t, Rcpp::NumericVector k) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector x = t/factorial(k);
      return x;
    }')
```